# Deploying Padrino via Capistrano with Sequel migrations

Tags: ruby, capistrano, sequel, padrino

I'm looking for the basic recipe to get my Sequel migrations running in production.  The local rake tasks are very nice (`sq:migrate`) but I haven't come across anything to get the migrations running on the production server.

Best to just roll my own cap task?